# SQL managing software to manage/edit querys

Tags: mysql, sql

I've got a database I need to migrate to a new format. Now I have lots of data and I need some help in changing the queries to the format the new database accepts. Does someone know software to manage and edit queries, maybe in some sort of column GUI?

I have Mac OS but can also use Windows. The databases are MySQL. I have no price limit :)

Answer (score 1):

TLDR version - local mysql server, local apache server w/ php support, and phpmyadmin

If you have your existing queries, and a sample dataset that hits all the combos, you could load it all up in phpMyAdmin and work with it in-browser.  View or create relationships, run queries, edit/delete/insert data, etc.  Save queries, export data, all sorts of good stuff.

Either set up MAMP, or do it in a VM via VirtualBox using a quick LAMP set up.  Personally, I recommend doing it on LAMP, with a nice GUI desktop

1. Download and install VirtualBox for Mac
2. Download a Linux Mint MATE edition 64bit installer ISO
3. Create a new VM, give it sufficient disk space dynamically allocated - it won't use the disk space until it has data to store on it.
4. Click through the installer for Mint, just take the defaults
5. On first boot, open a terminal and run

   sudo apt-get update
   sudo apt-get dist-upgrade

After updates are done, reboot the VM. Log back in, open a terminal, and run

```
sudo apt-get install apache2 libapache2-mod-php7.0 php7.0-mcrypt php7.0-mysql phpmyadmin
```

The VM will download and install all required packages, prompting you for some info along the way (mysql admin password to create, which webserver -apache2 - you want to configure for phpmyadmin, etc).  Almost always the default choice is a correct one.

After it is all done installing, open a browser (firefox is installed by default, or you can manually install chrome/chromium) and go to http://localhost/phpmyadmin .  Log in with the root username and whatever password you created during install, and there you are.